# CutePDF command line or equivilant

Tags: windows, command-line, cutepdf

Is it possible to run a command that will automatically print to file using [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/)?

I have tried this and still no luck: `print C:\test.doc /D:CPW2`

If not any other suggestion on how to automate a print to pdf / convert to pdf through a command line silently (freeware)

Comment: What kind of files are they? The program used to display, edit, and print the file will determine what terminal command should be used, if the command exists at all.

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: Do you need a specific output path or could it be the same path as the input path is? For example `print C:\test.doc` would create a new PDF file under `C:`

Comment: The path doesn't really matter, would prefer it to be the same as the input but that can be changed accordingly, the error im getting is: "Unable to initialize device CPW2" Although in printers this is the correct port. Im not sure whether its something to do with cutepdf itself

Comment: @AshKing Hello, I would be pleased if you could leave some feedback to know if I have to improve my answer.

Answer (score 5):

#### Simple solution

If the output path doesn't matter, you could try [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator) with the following commandline:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFCreator>PDFCreator.exe /NOSTART /PF"C:\test.doc"
```

1. Per GUI you have to enable *Use Auto-save* and set a auto-save path once.
   From now on, this path will be used every time you execute the command above
2. You have to set PDFCreator as your default printer

**Tip:**
Per GUI you can save your settings in a profile (.INI file) which can then be selected when you execute your command line. This way, you don't have to use *Auto-save* as default for every normal print (e.g. from Word or Excel)

```
PDFCreator.exe /NoStart /OptionsFile"C:\myprofile.ini" /PF"C:\test.doc"
```

---

#### Advanced solution

The advantage of the second solution is, that you don't have to set PDFCreator as your default printer and you have full control over the output file path and name

1. Install PDFCreator together with its [COM  module](http://docs.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator/latest/en/pdfcreator/com-interface/reference/settings/)
2. Copy & paste this code to a textfile and save it as `Convert2PDF.vbs`

   ```
   Set PDFCreator = Wscript.CreateObject("PDFCreator.clsPDFCreator", "PDFCreator_")
   With PDFCreator
    ReadyState = 0
    .cStart "/NoProcessingAtStartup"
    .cOption("UseAutosave") = 1
    .cOption("UseAutosaveDirectory") = 1
    .cOption("AutosaveFormat") = 0
    .cOption("AutosaveStartStandardProgram") = 0
    DefaultPrinter = .cDefaultprinter
    .cDefaultprinter = "PDFCreator"
    .cClearcache
    .cPrinterStop = false
    .cOption("AutosaveDirectory") = WScript.Arguments(1)
    .cOption("AutosaveFilename") = WScript.Arguments(2) 
    .cPrintfile cStr(WScript.Arguments(0))
     c = 0
     Do While (ReadyState = 0) and (c < 120)
      c = c + 1
      Wscript.Sleep 250
     Loop
    .cDefaultprinter = DefaultPrinter
    .cClearcache
    WScript.Sleep 200
    .cClose
   End With

   Public Sub PDFCreator_eReady()
    ReadyState = 1
   End Sub
   ```
3. You can execute your VBScript file from the command line with this syntax:
    `Convert2PDF.vbs "C:\input.doc" "C:\outputfolder" "outputfilename"`

Personally I use a [slightly different version](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f6b3aaa21c8a02b7242e) where the input and output folder+filename stays the same. I created a shortcut in my `shell:sendto` folder to easily convert files per right-click

[image]

Comment: I just tried your advanced method and nothing happened, but then again I'm trying to convert a .ppt to a .pdf

Comment: @OWiz Can you provide more details what you exactly have done?

Comment: I'm not sure if this solution is still viable. PdfForge released a new major version and their documentation changed