# Converting multiple CAD files to PDF with script (XP)

Tags: windows-xp, pdf, printing, vbscript, cad

Going off of what was covered in the thread [here](https://superuser.com/questions/614992/cutepdf-command-line-or-equivilant) I have 2 questions. (I'm using the [vbscript](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f6b3aaa21c8a02b7242e) version that's in my SendTo folder and works nicely, thank you [nixda](https://superuser.com/users/50173/nixda)! )

1. How can I modify the script to repeat for every file selected. For example if I select 5 files and right click then send to this script, it will convert all five files. I'm unsure of how to detect multiple selections and then use that information to loop the script.
2. I'm using a CAD sofware called designcad. Within the software I can print to PDF Creator and it produces a nice pdf, however sending the same designcad file to this script (which calls the PDF Creator) does not produce a pdf at all. Is there a log file for the PDF Creator where I can see the parameters involved when printing from within the designcad software?

(I'll keep the same file name for the pdf as well as keep the same folder, as the script is already configured to do)

I appreciate any help/ advice as to where to look

Answer (score 0):

I do not have these programs installed so I am unable to test this but I think you can leverage some of the built in Windows commands. The example I included below uses the [FORFILES](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551.aspx) command. Hope this helps or at least leads you in the right direction, else we can work it out.

```
FORFILES /p "YOURPATHHERE" /m *.*  /c "cmd /c if C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFCreator>PDFCreator.exe /NOSTART /PF @file"
```