# How to convert a ppt slideshow to a pdf?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-powerpoint, compression

For a training, I was given several large powerpoint files, each of which opens automatically like a slide show.  I can't find any way to edit them.  My goal is to compress them by converting them to pdf -- is there a way?  I just want to be able to refer back to the contents.  Static would be fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I automatically convert PowerPoint to PDF?](https://superuser.com/questions/641471/how-can-i-automatically-convert-powerpoint-to-pdf)

Comment: @mashuptwice - Do I have to use a script?

Comment: Note that several answers mention that the functionality is already built into powerpoint. You can also find a bunch of other questions regarding your problem here: https://superuser.com/search?q=ppt+to+pdf

Comment: @aparente001 [Microsoft says](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/save-powerpoint-presentations-as-pdf-files-9b5c786b-9c6e-4fe6-81f6-9372f77c47c8) you can export PowerPoint presentations as PDFs directly from within PowerPoint.

Comment: PDF is not a compression tool, and creating PDF is and has been built in to PowerPoint for quite a while now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > For a training, I was given several large powerpoint files, each of which opens automatically like a slide show.

Almost certainly because they've been saved as PPS or PPSX/PPSM files. These open automatically into slideshow view when you double-click them.

So don't do that. ;-)

Instead, start PowerPoint, then use File | Open to open the presentations.  They'll open in Normal (aka editing) view.

From there you can chose File | Save As and save as PDF.

There's no guarantee that a file saved as PDF will be smaller than the original PowerPoint file; it might be considerably larger if you use a Mac.

But at least now you know how to do it and can find out for yourself.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Each file went from 20 to 35 MB to less than 500 KB.

Comment: @aparente001 That's quite some diet you put them on. Congratulations!